# SVD of matrix with positive determinant

Tags: linear-algebra

Here is a quote from the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition#Intuitive_interpretations) on the SVD:

[image]

The article states that in the special case where $M$ has a positive determinant, $U$ and $V^*$ can be viewed as rotation matrices.  But then, in the next sentence, the article describes the first of three geometrical transformations as "a rotation or reflection".

Should the article not just say "a rotation" rather than "a rotation or reflection"?  The phrase "a rotation or reflection" seems to contradict the previous sentence, which asserted that $V^*$ can be viewed as a rotation matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Technically you are correct, but the matrices $U$ and $V$ needn't be proper rotations. Therefore the word reflections is included, which are improper rotations. There may be a better term for matrices which include both proper and improper rotations, but I think that term is simply rotation matrices.

Hope that helps!

Comment: So how are we using the fact that $\det M > 0$?